# Is it possible to use Dropdown inside of Popover without Closing Popover?

Tags: antd

I am trying use dropdown inside popover but it close everytime popover. I tried using different visible property on state but still same.

```
<div>
        <Dropdown 
                visible={visibleDropdown}
                onVisibleChange={(visible)=>this.onDropdownVisibleChange(visible)}
                overlay={
                <Menu>
                  <Menu.Item key="0">
                    <a href="http://www.alipay.com/">1st menu item</a>
                  </Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item key="1">
                    <a href="http://www.taobao.com/">2nd menu item</a>
                  </Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Divider />
                  <Menu.Item key="3">3d menu item</Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
              } trigger={['click']}>
                <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
                  Click me <Icon type="down" />
                </a>
              </Dropdown>
    </div>
```

This does not work am i missing something?

Comment: See https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/3438

Comment: yeah i saw it but i need use dropdonw not select. Because in my component, i want just add an item to an array only by selecting it,using Select i cannot  reinitialize select to show placeholder on each Select. So thats why i need dropdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around a bit, and here is a working solution:

http://codepen.io/JesperWe/pen/QvMNjJ

Just using getPopupContainer doesn't solve it, you have to play with the visible state a bit. Looking at the most important parts from the Codepen:

```
onVisibleChange = ( visible ) => {
    this.setState( { visible: true } )
};

closeDropdown = () => {
    this.setState( { visible: false } )
};

...

const menu = (
    <Menu onSelect={this.closeDropdown}>
        <Menu.Item>
            One
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>
            Two
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
);

return (
    <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={[ 'click' ]} getPopupContainer={this.getContainer}>
        <Button onClick={this.onVisibleChange}>Dropdown</Button>
    </Dropdown>
);

....

<Popover visible={this.state.visible}
     onVisibleChange={this.onVisibleChange} 
     placement="right"
     getPopupContainer={this.getContainer}
     trigger="click" content={this.renderContent()}>

    <Button icon="filter">click me</Button>

</Popover>
```

The trick is having `onVisibleChange` always set the state to `true`, and then closing the popover explicitly from the Dropdown overlay.

Comment: how do I dismiss popover if click outside